# Data Rest Repository Custom Annotated Query

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-rest

I'm working my way through the Spring Data-Rest guide and struggling writing a custom annotated query and not sure if it's even possible, here's the code:

**CategoryRepository**

```
package com.example.repositories

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RestResource

import com.example.entities.Category
import com.example.entities.InventoryDetail

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel="categories", path="categories")
interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Long> {

    @RestResource(path="inventoryByCategory",rel="inventoryByCategory")
    @Query("select new com.example.entities.InventoryDetail(i.id, i.item, c.name) from Category c join c.inventory i where upper(c.name) like upper(:name+'%')")
    Page<InventoryDetail> queryByCategoryStartsWithIgnoreCase(@Param("name") String name, Pageable pageable)

}
```

The query above is the one that I'm struggling with, not sure how to properly do this. I searched for hours looking for a solution but could not find one.

**Category Entity**

```
package com.example.entities

import javax.persistence.Column
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.FetchType
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue
import javax.persistence.GenerationType
import javax.persistence.Id
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn
import javax.persistence.OneToMany
import javax.persistence.Table

@Entity
@Table(name="categories")
class Category implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    long id

    @Column
    String name

    @Column
    String description

    @OneToMany(targetEntity=Inventory.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="category")
    List<Inventory> inventory

}
```

**Inventory Entity**

```
package com.example.entities

import javax.persistence.Column
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue
import javax.persistence.GenerationType
import javax.persistence.Id
import javax.persistence.Index
import javax.persistence.Table

@Entity
@Table(name="inventory", indexes=[ @Index(columnList="category", unique=false) ])
class Inventory implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    long id

    @Column
    long category

    @Column
    String item

    @Column
    String description

    @Column
    long price

    @Column
    long onHand
}
```

**InventoryDetail**

```
package com.example.entities

import javax.persistence.Column;

class InventoryDetail {

    long id

    String item

    String name

    InventoryDetail(long id, String item, String name) {
        this.id = id
        this.item = item
        this.name = name
    }

}
```

If I want to select specific fields from both entities, do I need to have a custom DTO like the one above? Is it possible to just use a `new map(...)` instead? Either way, the query runs and I see it in the console, but in the HAL browser it gives me a 500 error, I'm sure I am overlooking something, but not sure what it is.

I appreciate your help in advance!

**EDIT**

Here is the output from the Hibernate query:

```
Hibernate: select count(category0_.id) as col_0_0_ from categories category0_ inner join inventory inventory1_ on category0_.id=inventory1_.category where upper(category0_.name) like upper(?+'%')
Hibernate: select inventory1_.id as col_0_0_, inventory1_.item as col_1_0_, category0_.name as col_2_0_ from categories category0_ inner join inventory inventory1_ on category0_.id=inventory1_.category where upper(category0_.name) like upper(?+'%') limit ?
```

Comment: inner join only select common data from categories and inventory. Use left join if you need categories based inventory or right join if you need inventory based categories.

Comment: I tried both, left and right, and neither worked for me.

Comment: When I request from curl in the terminal, it doesn't return anything at all. When I run it from the HAL browser it returns `500 Internal Server Error`, and no errors in the STS console.

Comment: Please, check any other simple query works or not ?

Comment: Ok i got on issue in your query check this query: `select new com.example.entities.InventoryDetail(i.id, i.item, c.name) from Category c join c.inventory i where c.id= i.category and upper(c.name) like upper(:name+'%')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After countless hours of testing, I decided to throw the code in a controller and access it via the EntityManager, and it worked. After getting it to work from the controller I realized that JPA/Hibernate is expecting an Entity and not an Object/DTO.

I was able to do this...

```
List<Object> list(String name) {
    def qry = "select new map(i.id as id, i.item as item, c.name as category) from Category c join c.inventory i where upper(c.name) like upper(:name+'%')"
    List<Object> results = em.createQuery(qry).setParameter('name',name).getResultList()
    return results
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Query :

```
@Query("select new com.example.entities.InventoryDetail(i.id, i.item, c.name) from Category c join c.inventory i where upper(c.name) like upper(:name+'%')")
```

In your custom query no join mapping for Category and Inventory. Repace this line of code by following where  Category and Inventory mapped by their id in join:

```
 @Query("select new com.example.entities.InventoryDetail(i.id, i.item, c.name) from Category c join c.inventory i where c.id=i.category upper(c.name) like upper(:name+'%')")
```

Note: by default on jpql `join` means `inner join`

Comment: The join mapping is automatically there if you look at the hibernate query that i pasted in my question. By defining that in the entities, I did not have to define it in the query. It didn't work, I tried it.

Comment: Please add access modifier `public` in `Category`,`Inventory`,`InventoryDetail` class then check it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the cause of your 500 error, but I see something wrong with your query, particularly with how you concatenate the paramater `name` with the wildcard character `%`.

```
@Query("select new com.example.entities.InventoryDetail(i.id, i.item, c.name) from Category c join c.inventory i where upper(c.name) like upper(:name+'%')")
```

You must remove the plus sign and the single quotes.

```
@Query("select new com.example.entities.InventoryDetail(i.id, i.item, c.name) from Category c join c.inventory i where upper(c.name) like upper(:name%)")
```

See sample implementation [here](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-new-like-expressions-of-spring-data-jpa/).

Comment: I'm using Groovy for most of the project, I didn't get an error from that. The error was caused due to the fact that I was not returning an `Entity` which is what JPA/Hibernate is expecting.